# C# opengl Visualize in current Form

Tags: c#, forms, opengl, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I'm not experienced with C# well and have some problem with Forms.
I'am using VS 2013 to make my program with GUI. In the main form, one button start OpenGL visualization. Here is code of that button:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Glut.glutInit();                                                        
    Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_RGB);
    Glut.glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    Glut.glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Multiple View");
    init();
    Glut.glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    Glut.glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    Glut.glutKeyboardFunc(new Glut.KeyboardCallback(keyboard));
    Glut.glutMainLoop();
}
```

Everything works well, but this open new window and in my opionion doesnt looks good. Moreover, when I close the visualization window, ALL the program are closing.

I have 2 questions:

1) Is there (in VS13, C#) any form (buttons, textboxes [haha] and so on) that can I use to visualize in current, main form ? When button is pressed, the visualization starts in "that" MainForm area. Name / simple code / links please.

2) If not, what I need to do, to close ONLY the visualization window, not all the program ?

Thanks for help

Comment: You can basically render to every Windows-Forms control you want. The way how you create the context for a given HWND (aka .Handle in C#) depends on the library you use to create the context.

Comment: Use Opentk for OpenGl Projects (Read a book or a rich tutorial). Use GDI+ for Winform projects.